# How to Authenticate My web application's backend APIs with Microsoft office word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to get an access token from word add-in and send it to my backend and authenticate the word user and connect the account with my web application's account. This is to link the user with their account in my web application.

I tried using:

```
Office.context.auth.getUserIdentityTokenAsync --> this is deprecated API, so it didnt work.
Office.context.auth.getAccessToken --> is not a function
Office.context.webAuth.getAuthContextAsync --> An internal error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getAccessToken` API to get an access token that contains the identity for the current user signed in to Office. The access token is also an ID token because it contains identity claims about the signed in user, such as their name and email. You can also use the ID token to identify the user when calling your own web services. To call `getAccessToken` you must configure your Office Add-in to use SSO with Office.

To use SSO with Office, you need to create an app registration in the Azure portal so the Microsoft identity platform can provide authentication and authorization services for your Office Add-in and its users. Read more about that in the [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) article.

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Word) {
    document.getElementById("getIDToken").onclick = getIDToken;
  }
});

async function getIDToken() {
  try {
    let userTokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
      allowSignInPrompt: true,
    });
    let userToken = jwt_decode(userTokenEncoded);
    document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML =
      "name: " +
      userToken.name +
      "<br>email: " +
      userToken.preferred_username +
      "<br>id: " +
      userToken.oid;
    console.log(userToken);
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML =
      "An error occurred. <br>Name: " +
      error.name +
      "<br>Code: " +
      error.code +
      "<br>Message: " +
      error.message;
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

See [Create a Node.js Office Add-in that uses single sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs) for more information.

Comment: I am facing this error for this method as well , 

OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'API Not Supported', message: 'The identity API is not supported for this add-in.', code: 13000}

Comment: Make sure that your host application supports `Idendtity API 1.3`, see [Identity API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/identity-api-requirement-sets?view=powerpoint-js-preview) for more information.